# Unexpected login prompt for test user in iOS sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I am testing in-app purchase and restoration. Testing was going fine until I tried to switch test users.

I mistakenly tried to sign in via Settings ("iTunes & App Store"), where I signed out as Test User 1 and started to sign in as Test User 2. When the App Store gave me "This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes Store, etc." and prompted for my credit card information, I realized my mistake and cancelled the sign-in.

But now every time I run my app via XCode, it prompts me to "Sign In to iTunes Store" as Test User 1. I cancel it and then everything proceeds normally. But I would like to get rid of this weird behavior.

I have tried signing in. That doesn't stop it. Then I tried going into Settings ("iTunes & App Store") and signing out. That also doesn't stop it. Also tried rebooting phone and then a hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away overnight. It may have beeen a caching issue with the sandbox and/or App Store.